# Select First Row from each group when many columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table as follows:

```
Name Part  Address City   ... Stuff 
Bob   X1     Y1      Z1   ... Stuff1
Bob   X2     Y1      Z1   ... Stuff1       
Bob   X3     Y1      Z1   ... Stuff1
Susan V1     Y2      Z2   ... Stuff2
Susan V2     Y2      Z2   ... Stuff2
....
```

Here, Stuff is many columns. Notice that Address, City, Stuff doesn't change.

So I just want to return the first row. I know I need to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
GROUP_BY (NAME)
```

but I'm not sure how to select the first row only after the group by? I saw other posts but they all were selecting based upon a min.. since my columns aren't numeric, I'm not sure how they would apply?

Comment: You need to define *first row*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) instead.

> Returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result
>   set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Part)
    FROM tbl
) AS t
WHERE rn = 1
```

You can replace the `ORDER BY` column depending on your definition of first.

Comment: Is there a `t` after the closing parenthesis above the last line?

Comment: Yes, a subquery must be aliased.

Comment: Note: you still need to define the 'first'. In this case it is assumed this is defined by the column `Part`

Comment: Hi, yes, that's correct. To be honest -- any observation within each group will do.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 WITH CTE
    AS
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupColumn ORDER BY SomeColumn) as indx
        FROM YourTABLENAME
    )

    select * from CTE where indx=1
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use top1

```
     SELECT top(1) Name FROM myTable GROUP_BY (NAME),
```

in groupby, **you cannot show column that is not in groupby with out using aggrigrate function**

so you have option to do like

```
SELECT top(1) Name,Address, City FROM myTable GROUP_BY NAME,Address, City
```

or

```
SELECT top(1) Name,stuff((select ','+Address+city from myTable mt where mt.Name=myTable.Name for xmlpath('')),1,1,'') FROM myTable GROUP_BY NAME
```

Comment: Why use group by? It's unnecessary.

Comment: it was in his example